# How to interpret linear equation of IMU output for sensor calibration

Tags: sensor, imu, calibration

I created a system to measure angle in between two IMUs in 1-axis by getting the difference between their rolls. I then applied a kalman filter that takes into consideration the roll angle and gyroscope readings.

To test the sensor readings, I took note of the actual angle between the IMUs using a protractor. The interval between the angle samples is fixed, I can't change it. Here is the sample:

[image]

From what I've researched, I'm supposed to graph them and get the linear equation which I've done, but I can't understand how to interpret the process and the difference between their respective line equation. How do I explain this for a write-up and how will I be able to calibrate using these data?

EDIT: I didn't know the graph was supposed to be Actual vs Sensor readings, my bad. I added this new graph:

[image]

Comment: Don’t you want your actual values on the x-axis, so you get the resulting equation for mapping sensor value to actual value? Use XY plot.

Comment: @winny Thanks for the edit. I added the XY plot now. Do you have any references I can read in order to interpret this plot?

Comment: No references, but you have your gain and offset values straight from excel to do the calculation backwards in your application from sensor value to actual. If you want even more accuracy, I would suggest a look-up table.